# GTK3+ and C++ on OSX - "No GSettings schemas are installed" error

Tags: x11, c, gtk, glib

I'm trying to run a C++ example with GTK3+ and GStreamer components on OSX. I can gcc compile the source with:

`gcc -o basic5 basic-tutorial-5.c 'pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 gtk+3.0'`

but when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
GLib-GIO-ERROR **: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
```

I read somewhere to try gsettings list-schemas. That resulted in:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: @illuminÉ I can't see the 'schemas'. How do I reinstall the schemas component?

Comment: On Linux the package is called `gsettings-desktop-schemas` but I don't know how you install your stuff on OSX. In my case if the schemas were absent after installing, I would need to do `glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` to generate them I think. If you can't find a directory named _schemas_, then you have to find a way to install that component and link it to what you're doing. I gather so from something like [this](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/38634).

Comment: I know that Slackware, at least, calls glib-compile-schemas on each boot. Installers should really do that, but in case they or you forget it's a decent option.